# Python 3: installed but couldn't call virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I successfully installed virtualenv on my Mac. Then I try to use it in my project by "virtualenv xxx". However, it couldn't find the command ... anyone knows what was missing in the process below? Thanks!

```
edamame$ pip3 install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.8MB 304kB/s 
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv-15.1.0

edamame$ cd Documents/myprojects

edamame$ mkdir test_virenv_proj
edamame$ cd test_virenv_proj/
edamame$ ls
edamame$ virtualenv venv
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

Comment: Try `python3 -mvirtualenv venv`. Maybe the bin path of the Python modules is not in your $PATH

Comment: works as suggested. Thank you! How do I set it to $PATH as well?